# Apache2 redirect to https

Tags: http, redirect, https, apache2, virtualhost

For one of my customer projects, I have a domain name abc.my-app.com. My server public IP is x.y.z.a .

I have developed a Spring boot based application. In the application, I have configured automatic redirect from http port 8088 to https 8443. 
The application is accessible as https://x.y.z.a:8443/ without issues. 
The application is also redirected to https when accessed as http://x.y.z.a:8088 
in the browser.

Refer https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/ on how I have configured this.

I also have setup apache 2.4.18 version on my server. I have configured virtual hosts to be able to redirect to https when my application is accessed from browser as https://abc.my-app.com to https://abc.my-app.com:8443.

But, if user accesses http://abc.my-app.com (without https), the apache does not redirect to my application on https.

How do I enable Apache to redirect from http://abc.my-app.com to https://abc.my-app.com?

My Virtual host configuration is below:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80 *:8080 *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@xyzc
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.key
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # Servers to proxy the connection, or
    # List of application servers Usage

    ProxyPass / https://x.y.z.a:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://x.y.z.a:8443/
    ServerName ip-x-y-z-a
    </VirtualHost>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. Not sure though this is the right way.
In Spring boot application, I configured redirect from port 80 to port 443. 
Apache2 redirects from 443  to my application running on port 8443.